# Need advice with my average calculator code

Tags: c++

Good day,

I need help with my below code. I have a problem with calculating the average.
The code works as it should expect for calculating the average of the second entry.

I have highlighted the average that does not add up in the below picture. Its weird that the average is only not adding up on the second entry?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

float snelheid[][50] = {{}};
float lading[] = {};
float snelheidGem[] = {0};
int ladingNo = 1;
int snelheidToets = 1;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hoeveel ladings word getoets?: ";
    cin >> ladingNo;

    for (int i = 0; i < ladingNo; i++)
    {
        int n = i + 1;
        if (n == 1 || n == 8 || n > 19)
        {
            cout <<"Wat was die " << n << "st lading?: ";
            cin >> lading[i];
            cout <<"Hoeveel skote was geskiet vir die "<< n << "st lading?: ";
            cin >> snelheidToets;
            snelheidGem[i] = {0};
            for (int t = 0; t < snelheidToets; t++)
            {
                int m = t + 1;
                if (m == 1 || m == 8 || m > 19)
                {
                    cout <<"Wat was die spoed van die " << m << "st skoot?: ";
                    cin >> snelheid[i][t];
                }
                else
                {
                    cout <<"Wat was die spoed van die " << m << "de skoot?: ";
                    cin >> snelheid[i][t];
                }
                snelheidGem[i]=snelheidGem[i]+snelheid[i][t];
            }
            snelheidGem[i] = snelheidGem[i]/snelheidToets;
            cout << snelheidGem [i] << endl;
            cout << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cout <<"Wat is die " << n << "de lading?: ";
            cin >> lading[i];
            cout <<"Hoeveel skote was geskiet vir die "<< n << "de lading?: ";
            cin >> snelheidToets;
            snelheidGem[i] = {0};
            for (int t = 0; t < snelheidToets; t++)
            {
                snelheid[i][t] = {0};
                int m = t + 1;
                if (m == 1 || m == 8 || m > 19)
                {
                    cout <<"Wat was die spoed van die " << m << "st skoot?: ";
                    cin >> snelheid[i][t];
                }
                else
                {
                    cout <<"Wat was die spoed van die " << m << "de skoot?: ";
                    cin >> snelheid[i][t];
                }
                snelheidGem[i]=snelheidGem[i]+snelheid[i][t];
                cout << snelheid[i][t] << " snelheid" << endl;
                cout << snelheidGem[i] << " gemiddeld" << endl;

            }
            snelheidGem[i] = snelheidGem[i]/snelheidToets;
            cout << snelheidGem [i] << endl;
            cout << endl;

        }

    }

    return 0;
}
```

[Average calculation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EWnJ.png)

Comment: Welcome! It might be a good idea to either comment your code or use english names for at least the variable names so that we can understand your code.

Comment: You're (un)lucky that your code even compiles. Plain C++ arrays are fixed-sized. You must specify a constant size when you declare them and you change the size later. Stuff such as `float lading[] = {};` create zero or one element arrays so trying to use them will cause a lot of problems.

Comment: Create functions. Don't do everything in function main. If you split the program into classes and functions it will become much more clear.

Comment: Hi,
Much appreciated. I will follow your advice and split the program up into classes and functions.

I will define the array size and see if that works.

Answer (score 2):

On this line:

```
float snelheidGem[] = {0};
```

you are creating an array of size 1, but are then indexing elements such as `snelheidGem[1]`, and `snelheidGem[2]`, etc, which invokes undefined behavior (UB). UB means anything can happen, including giving the correct average sometimes, but not at other times.

You can give it a sufficiently large size:

```
float snelheidGem[50] = {0};
```

or much better, use a `std::vector`, to which you can add elements by doing `push_back`.

Note that you have the same issue with:

```
float lading[] = {};
```